# Changing the background colour of a JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

One part of a program I'm creating is a non-editable text area that provides information and hyperlinks. I'm doing this with a JEditorPane, but I'd like to change the background colour from the default white. I've searched for solutions online, but the only ones I can find are for JTextPanes, in which some of the methods used don't apply to editor panes. This is the class I've been using to create my interface, using GroupLayout.

```
public class MainViewDisplay extends JFrame {

    JEditorPane editorPane;
    JScrollPane jScrollPane;

    public MainViewDisplay() {
        this.initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        editorPane = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        editorPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jScrollPane.setViewportView(editorPane);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 521, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 336, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        pack();
    }
}
```

For some reason the `setBackground()` method isn't changing the colour when the program runs. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Works fine for me. The background will be "overridden" by the document displayed by the editor pane, so beware of that

Comment: If you have control over the HTML content, you can set the background color of the `<body>` element.